# ChartJS charts width and height set to 0 when responsive and dragged. Any ideas as to why?

Tags: chart.js, vuejs3, vue-chartjs, vue.draggable

I am in the process of building a dashboard with multiple charts on it. For a chart library I've landed on [VueChartJS,](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#browser) with the [vue-chart-3](https://vue-chart-3.netlify.app/) wrapper and for a drag n drop library I'm using [vue-draggable-next](https://github.com/anish2690/vue-draggable-next).

The issue I'm having is that if the charts have the responsive option as true and you drag them, their height and width are set to 0. I added a toggle to prove that it's an issue with the responsive feature, but is there anything else I can do to remedy this issue?

Right now I'm wondering if I need to make some invisible toggle that activates every time you click the chart to drag it around and then toggles off when you are done dragging, but that seems like a lot of potential code and time to impliment this feature and wonder if there's not just a better way to do this?

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

I've made a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/draggable-charts-8uck7?file=/src/components/Chart2.vue) to show the issue and there is a gif below as well showing what is happening.

[image]

Comment: Strange, I am unable to reproduce the bug you mention. Drag and drop works as expected in Chrome 95. What browser do you use?

Comment: @adelriosantiago Thank you for the comment! try toggling the responsiveness. Currently I have it set to false and it is draggable, but once you make it responsive, it disappearing upon dragging